# Arrays and Pointers, which is the better way to write in similar situations

Tags: c

Is there anyway to write the code without having to initialise the size of the array?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXSIZE 100

int main()
{
    int i,n;
    int num[MAXSIZE];
    printf("Enter the value of n\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter the list of integers\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++);
        scanf("%d",&num[i]);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d\t",num[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

I used MAXSIZE since the compiler required me to initialise the size, an error came up everytime I left the size blank. All this because incase the user wants to input more than 100 values, how do i accomodate him?

Is using pointers a better way to write the program?
I tried by changing

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int *num,n,i;
    printf("Enter the value of n\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter the list of integers\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++);
        scanf("%d",num+i);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d\t",*(num+i)); 
    return 0;
}
```

This is giving me a warning saying uninitialised local variable in visual studio and isn't inputting all the numbers. Output is garbage values.
Dev c++ crashes everytime I execute.
Any advice would be helpful, Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a compiler that supports variable-length arrays (C99 or later, although VLAs are now optional under C2011) *and* the size of the array is relatively small, you can do the following:

```
int i, n;
...
scanf( "%d", &n );
int num[n]; 
// load and print num as before
```

If your compiler does not support VLAs or the array size is large (more than a few hundred K), then you will want to allocate memory dynamically using either `malloc` or `calloc`:

```
int i, n;
...
scanf( "%d", &n );
int *num = malloc( n * sizeof *num );
// load and print num as before
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use just a plain pointer, you still need to allocate memory for the array. We can do that with malloc!

```
int *num,n,i;
printf("Enter the value of n\n");
scanf("%d",&n);

num = malloc(sizeof(*num) * n);

printf("Enter the list of integers\n");
...
```

Also, even though you are using pointers, you can still write `num[i]` instead of `*(num +i)`. In fact, those two expressions are always interchangeable, and so you you should use the one that makes your code the most readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) if you want user to put the size of array (run program in C99 ode. Use the option: `-std=c99`).
Arrays are used when you need small memory. If you need some large amount of memory then go with pointers and dynamic allocation. When using pointer, initialize it to some memory location before any access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are ***NOT*** pointers !

Their types types are completely different and are treated differently by the compiler.

```
int *num ;
```

declares `num` as pointer to `int`, which is not pointing to any *valid* memory address
("uninitialized" as reported by compiler ) . Whatever operation you're doing in second case invokes undefined behaviour

You need to point it to a *valid* memory location, in this case by using `malloc` call

```
num = malloc( sizeof( int ) * n);
```